# Working with data from parent component

Tags: angular, components

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'aricle-root',
  template: '<li>{{article}}</li>'
})

export class Article {
  @Input() article: object;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.article); //undefined
  }
}
```

So when i pass the variable `{{artical}}` from my parent component to this one and it recieves it and renders it ok, but what if i want to do something with that variable like print it on the console for an example. It seems to be always undefined

Comment: You try to print it in the constructor only ?

Comment: just tell me how can i access its value in that class, if you know, please

Comment: print the variable on ngOnInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor your variable is not set yet. You can access when setted :

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'aricle-root',
  template: '<li>{{article}}</li>'
})

export class Article implements OnChanges {
  @Input() article: object;

  constructor() {

  }
  ngOnChanges(model){
     console.log(article)
  }
}
```

Comment: just a little addit, we should have `implements OnChanges` on the class or my editor complains about it :d

Comment: You're absolutely rigth, I made the change.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to get an intimation when your `Input` binding changes. You could use `ngOnChanges` hook to keep eye on `Input` property changes, and place the code in it.

```
//import { SimpleChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
   console.log(changes)
}
```